# meaning of "dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

This is from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch.
Here I'm supposed to do inside the chroot environment,

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
```

Is it telling the OS that "from now on, when you install packages, whatever the package is(--local), if that package tries to install /sbin/initctl, install it(--add) to /sbin/initctl.distrib (--rename)" ? I tried to understand the manual but couldn't understand it exactly.

Is it that if a file is diverted to another file by this dpkg-divert command(say, xfile to xfile.distrib) by a package, then when the package is used, xfile.distrib is used instead of original xfile?
I tried `cat /var/lib/dpkg/diversions` and it gives me this list.

```
/usr/share/dict/words
/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common
dictionaries-common
/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz
dash
/usr/share/man/man1/dh_gstscancodecs.1.gz
...
```

The file constins the list of files and not the package names and I can't understand it. For example what does the first line `/usr/share/dic/words` mean?
Please someone confirm me if my understanding is correct and what the list means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it telling the OS that "from now on, when you install packages, whatever the package is(--local), if that package tries to install /sbin/initctl, install it(--add) to /sbin/initctl.distrib (--rename)"

- `--rename` tells it to move any existing file immediately
- I'd put `--add`  next to "telling the OS"

> Is it that if a file is diverted to another file by this dpkg-divert command(say, xfile to xfile.distrib) by a package, then when the package is used, xfile.distrib is used instead of original xfile?

No. Whoever set up the diversion has to provide something in place of this `xfile` (in this case, that's you). In that page, they do:

> ```
> ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
> ```

---

The `diversions` file consists of three-line groups:

1. The file to be diverted
2. The diverted location
3. The package that set up the diversion

So for the following three lines:

```
/usr/share/dict/words
/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common
dictionaries-common
```

`dpkg` will divert installations of `/usr/share/dict/words` from packages other than `dictionaries-common` (say, `wamerican`, for example) to `/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common`. If you install `wamerican`, you can see this in action:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/share/dict/words
diversion by dictionaries-common from: /usr/share/dict/words
diversion by dictionaries-common to: /usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common
wamerican: /usr/share/dict/words
```

---

That guide is a bit outdated: `initctl` is Upstart, which is no longer used. You can't even install it anymore. Service management is done using systemd, and now you use `systemctl` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I can now almost understand it. A question, now that other packages will install into the diverted location(file), then will that other packages use the new diverted (name-changed) file instead of original file? so my question is if the diversion only for installation or for actual use other than the package who setup the diversion.  (and Yes I knew the LiveCDFromScratch guide above is too old so it's almost unusable. I hope ubuntu people update those documents.)

Comment: Nobody other than `dpkg` and the creator of the diversion knows about the diversion. Anybody using `/path/to/some/file` that was diverted will use whatever is currently there.

Comment: @muru I don't even have initctl  in /sbin.   only init.  Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS \n \l

What does those lines did , when it made sense?   to keep init process in safe?

Comment: @CEOatApartico in the steps after that, several packages are installed. Some packages start or restart services upon installation, and this was done using the `initctl` command. Since there's no point to doing that in the chroot (and it would cause errors because init isn't running in the chroot), they replace it with `true` for the rest of the setup.